# How can I access Google PostgreSQL shell when using private IP and VPC connector?

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have my PostgreSQL database in private network and connection with my API deployed on App Engine is based on VPC Connector. Everything seems to be working properly (connection between App and PostgreSQL) however I can not connect and just open PostgreSQL shell. When I try to connect via GCP portal and cloud instance I get

```
It seems your client does not have ipv6 connectivity and the database instance does not have an ipv4 address. Please request an ipv4 address for this database instance.
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As per the error message you shared and for the description of your issue, it seems like your Cloud SQL instance does not have public IP address assigned. As of today, "gcloud sql connect" command from [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#cloud-shell) requires the instance to have a public IP.

I have a few workarounds for you:

1. Create a GCE instance in the same network where Cloudsql
   Instance resides, then make necessary firewall configuration changes
   to allow it connect to your Cloud SQL instance via private IP
   address.
2. Create a GCE instance in the same network where Cloudsql
   Instance resides, Use "[gcloud beta sql connect](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/sql/connect)", which connects
   to your instance through Cloud SQL Proxy. You might need to set up
   service account and/or credentials file to make this work. Note :-
   Cloud SQL proxy should be configured in GCE instance in order to
   connect cloudsql instance using 'gcloud beta sql connect' command.
3. Assign a public IP address to your Cloud SQL instance.